# Azure Data Factory Performance Issue - Until Activity Loop Exist consumes Lot of Time

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have created a pipeline where I have used an until activity to iterate through the files and load the data into a SQL table. The logic used in the until activity expression is compared to the number of files available in the data lake with an incremental variable value. If the variable value is equal to or greater than the total number of files the loop will exit.

If we have less than 5 files in the data lake then the loop may exit within 1 minute but if we have more than 25 it takes nearly 8 minutes to exit the loop. AS the value of the count of files increases the time taken to exit the loop also increases.

For Eg: **We have 35 Files, all the files got processed and even the last activity inside the loop also successfully got executed, but the "until" activity again runs for another 12-14 minutes without any further activity to get executed.**

Any help to improve the performance of the until activity loop exit would be really helpful.

NB: Our pipeline requires sorting/failure exit/and other logical implementation methods that's why we did not use the for-each loop activity.

Regards,
Sandeep

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using Until?  The pattern I would use here is the Get Metadata activity to get the list of files in the lake, and then a For Each loop to import them.  The great thing about For Each in Data Factory is that it automatically runs in parallel, so more than one file would be imported.  If you disable this option then it would run only one file at a time, in serial, like your pattern.  Post back if you want to know more.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance#data-integration-units), we can scale up the DIU to improve the performance.
We can increase the `Computer type` and `Core count` when creating the IR.
[image]

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer, thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. We have tried changing the integration runtime configurations in the early phase of the development itself still, I will give it a try and let you know if it works.                                                                                                                                                                 We have tried changing the until activity conditions also, everything ends up with the same issue.